# The Kafka Rest Api does not work with two or more consumers in the same group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

Sometime after connecting a second consumer with the same group id, I get the error

> "Consumer instance not found" (code: 40403).

I noticed that when connecting the second consumer, my request to receive new messages from `Kafka` freezes for both consumers. I am convinced that the error I am getting is the result of the problem, not the cause because, after the request freezes, a timeout passes for the consumer and it is automatically deleted. However, I don't understand why the request hangs.

At the time of the problem, `Kafka's` queue is empty.

The configuration is set to:

```
zookeeper.connect
bootstrap.servers
```

Other values are set by default.

I thought this was due to the restriction of consumer threads (`consumer.threads`), but the documentation says that the default value is `50`.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/config.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What version are you running?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt 4.0.3

Comment: That's kinda old. Latest is 5.4. I'd suggest upgrading and then seeing if the issue remains.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the problem was in my version. For it, the value is consumer.threads is set to 1. Thanks